# Select Duplicate Sub String of Records to Single Record Using Group By

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible writing SQL to select duplicate sub string of records from a table into single records ? I just want to group the **month** and **year** so the result look like this picture:

[image]

I try this, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT DATE, SUBSTRING(DATE, 3, 6) as Addrow FROM dbo.n4abs_premi_olah GROUP BY Addrow
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y')) month
FROM Table
```

If you actually need to use `GROUP BY` (because you're also selecting other aggregates), do:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y')) month, other stuff...
FROM Table
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar.
But, I have a problem: What if the column 'date' not a date. I mean it might be a string, for example 'name' with records "Jefferson", "Brondon", "Anna", "Vanna" I like the result as "on" and "nna". How?

Comment: You can use a function like `SUBSTR()` to get the part of the string you care about, and use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in the same way.

Comment: Thx again Barmar!
I try this and works. SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(DATE, 4, 7) as Addrow FROM TABLE ORDER BY Addrow.
But it get error when I try to select other columns. 
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(DATE, 4, 7) as Addrow, Column1, Column2 FROM TABLE ORDER BY Addrow. 
How fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't get an error from that. But DISTINCT applies to all the columns you name, so it may not produce the results you want. If you just want to group by a particular column, use GROUP BY.

Comment: Hmm. Yes! you're right Barmar. I mean this get error:
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(DATE, 4, 7) as Addrow, Column1, Column2 FROM TABLE GROUP BY Addrow

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Invalid column name 'Addrow'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27995/discussion-between-philips-tel-and-barmar)

Comment: You shouldn't use both DISTINCT and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of many ways to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(MONTH(date), '/', YEAR(date)) FROM table;
```

Comment: What if column 'date' is a 'string' as I ask @Barmar comment?
thx

Comment: I gotta say, that's a weird request :) Something like `select 'on' from table where col like '%on%' union select 'nna' from table where col like '%nna%'`. The `union` will make the results distinct, so if you're just looking for one substring (and not doing a `union`) then start with `select distinct`.